# No libtvm.so and libtvm_runtime.so found in TVM Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, tvm, apache-tvm

I am new to Apache TVM.

I tried to build and launch a docker image named `tvm.ci_cpu:latest` as described in the tutorial https://tvm.apache.org/docs/install/docker.html#docker-source.

I tried to use the python application `tvmc` inside docker container as described in the tutorial https://tvm.apache.org/docs/tutorial/tvmc_command_line_driver.html#using-tvmc.

Then I got the following error:

```
$ tvmc --help

bash: tvmc: command not found
```

I tried to use the other method mentioned in the article above, but I got the following new error:

```
$ python3 -m tvm.driver.tvmc --help

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/opt/share0/bob/project/tvm/python/tvm/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from ._ffi.base import TVMError, __version__, _RUNTIME_ONLY
  File "/opt/share0/bob/project/tvm/python/tvm/_ffi/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .base import register_error
  File "/opt/share0/bob/project/tvm/python/tvm/_ffi/base.py", line 71, in <module>
    _LIB, _LIB_NAME = _load_lib()
  File "/opt/share0/bob/project/tvm/python/tvm/_ffi/base.py", line 51, in _load_lib
    lib_path = libinfo.find_lib_path()
  File "/opt/share0/bob/project/tvm/python/tvm/_ffi/libinfo.py", line 146, in find_lib_path
    raise RuntimeError(message)
RuntimeError: Cannot find libraries: ['libtvm.so', 'libtvm_runtime.so']
List of candidates:
/opt/sgxsdk/lib64/libtvm.so
/opt/share0/bob/project/tvm/libtvm.so
/usr/local/sbin/libtvm.so
/usr/local/bin/libtvm.so
/usr/sbin/libtvm.so
/usr/bin/libtvm.so
/sbin/libtvm.so
/bin/libtvm.so
/opt/rust/bin/libtvm.so
/usr/lib/go-1.10/bin/libtvm.so
/opt/share0/bob/project/tvm/python/tvm/libtvm.so
/opt/share0/bob/project/libtvm.so
/opt/sgxsdk/lib64/libtvm_runtime.so
/opt/share0/bob/project/tvm/libtvm_runtime.so
/usr/local/sbin/libtvm_runtime.so
/usr/local/bin/libtvm_runtime.so
/usr/sbin/libtvm_runtime.so
/usr/bin/libtvm_runtime.so
/sbin/libtvm_runtime.so
/bin/libtvm_runtime.so
/opt/rust/bin/libtvm_runtime.so
/usr/lib/go-1.10/bin/libtvm_runtime.so
/opt/share0/bob/project/tvm/python/tvm/libtvm_runtime.so
/opt/share0/bob/project/libtvm_runtime.so
```

I tried to pull and use the following third-party docker images instead of the ones I built myself:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/tvmai/ci-cpu
- https://hub.docker.com/r/tvmai/demo-cpu

However, I still met same problems as before.

WHY? I had no idea at all.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [pingsutw](https://discuss.tvm.apache.org/u/pingsutw)'s answer in https://discuss.tvm.apache.org/t/import-tvm-returns-runtime-error-cant-find-libtvm-so-when-using-docker-demo-cpu-image/5110. After referring to his advice, I tried rebuilding tvm in a container launched from the image `tvm.ci_cpu:latest` which built by myself.

```
pushd path/to/tvm && \
    chmod +x 3rdparty/libbacktrace/configure && \
    mkdir -p cmake-build && \
    cmake -H. -Bcmake-build -DUSE_LLVM=ON && \
    cmake --build cmake-build --target all -- -j 4 && \
    mv cmake-build build && \
    popd
```

After the above, I tried typing the command `python3 -m tvm.driver.tvmc --help` and got the following output.

```
usage: tvmc [-v] [--version] [-h] {run,tune,compile} ...

TVM compiler driver

optional arguments:
  -v, --verbose       increase verbosity
  --version           print the version and exit
  -h, --help          show this help message and exit.

commands:
  {run,tune,compile}
    run               run a compiled module
    tune              auto-tune a model
    compile           compile a model.

TVMC - TVM driver command-line interface
```

As you can see it works now.

Surprisingly, `libtvm.so` and `libtvm_runtime.so` are not pre-built in the tvm docker image. Maybe the [third-party tvm docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/tvmai/ci-cpu/tags) is broken. Maybe the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/apache/tvm/tree/main/docker) for building tvm docker image should be updated. Maybe it is designed to be flexibly compiled to meet various needs.

Comment: Only rebuilding tvm under the directory `path/to/tvm/build/` will work.

Comment: Type the command `alias tvmc="python3 -m tvm.driver.tvmc"` before using the command `tvmc <OPTION>`.